# Font not found AAPT error when creating realase apk

Tags: android

Font works fine but when i generate **Release Apk** i get error. APK is not build. There is a "(debug)" text after font as seen in the image

[image: as seen in the image]

Error

```
 AAPT: error: resource font/proxima_nova_egular (aka com.app.hellodoctor.patient:font/proxima_nova_egular) not found.
```

**Solution**

Change font file location from this

```
 app\src\debug\res\font
```

to this

```
 app\src\main\res\font
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes as you can see those fonts are in `font` directory but for `debug` configuration.

Select `Project` from the dropdown above, where currently `android` is selected, then you will be able to see two different directories of font. One of them should be `debug` dierctory. Now cut and paste those two fonts from the `font-debug` directory to normal `font` directory and the generate release build.

Comment: you can create common font directory and reference it in both debug and release through gradle

Comment: @IrfanUlHaq That is what I answered. I asked to move fonts from debug to the default directory of font.